# How to write a press release

Tags: marketing, press-release

I have to write a press release (intended for radio) for a fundraiser and I'm not sure on the format it should take. Should a press release be an information sheet or should it be the copy I want read out ? A lot of the sample press releases I've read sound like the latter.

This is what I've written thus far, any advice is appreciated.

> Do you like vodka? The Rotaract Club of ___ announces it's annual
>   vodka tasting fundraiser.
>
> The Rotaract Club of ____ is holding it's annual vodka tasting night
>   and popup bar on Friday March 13 at The National Club benefitting the
>   local charity Homes First which provides housing support to the
>   homeless.
>
> This is not your typical tasting, but a tasting with a twist. We skip
>   the lecture and get straight to the vodka; with interactive tastings
>   throughout the night where you can learn a bit more about you drink.
>   The night has a DJ, silent auction, raffle prizes and vodka! Our popup
>   bar has non vodka options too. A ticket gets you in the door, THREE
>   vodka cocktails or shots and appetizers. Discounted tickets for $40
>   are on sale until January 31, prices go up on February 1.  Tickets can
>   be found on Uniiverse.com, just search for Friday 13th Vodka.
>
> Homes First currently provides a home and support to more than 550
>   seniors, families, and single adults. Their shelters and housing
>   projects are all located throughout the Greater Toronto Area and they
>   remain one of the largest providers of homes for people with the
>   fewest options in Toronto.
>
> Rotaract is a volunteer organization made up of young professionals
>   who support local and international charitable causes through
>   volunteer work and fundraising. Rotaract is part of Rotary
>   International, better known to most as they Rotary Club.
>
> For more information please contact the Rotaract Club of Toronto's
>   fundraiser chair, X at x.y@gmail.com or 999-999-9999
>
> Thank you for your assistance.
>
> Best Regards, X

Comment: I like that release. "This is not your typical tasting, but a tasting with a twist. We skip the lecture and get straight to the vodka."

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple press release template:

I suggest you follow this image, it is simple but easy to understan:

[image]

Business Press Release Template:

---

[Business Name/Contact Info]
FOR IMMEDIATE RELEASE
[Location] -  Hagens Media, LLC. is pleased to these announce these new products starting on 1/1/2012.
[Details]
[More Details]

[Possible A Quote From CEO or Expert]

Answer (score 0):

In general, press releases should basically sound like the article you would like to see written (or announcement you want to hear read).  The reason is that the person who gets the press release is likely to be busy.  In many cases, your copy might be used exactly as you provided it.

The only caveat is that you don't want to sound too overly promotional --even though it's a press release, most news organizations will shy away from something that reads like an advertisement.

In this case, you might want to dial back some of the promotional details in favor of highlighting the newsworthy aspects of the event.